# Why does the pow() function in C++ not work for me here?

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm trying to make a table that prints daily compounding interest at different rates over time, but the pow() function does not appear to be working for me.  Here is my code:

```
double balance = principle * pow( (1 + (i / 36000)), (j * 360) );
printf( "%15.2f", balance);
```

Where i is the interest rate and j is the year.  However, the print statement only ever prints the original principle because the pow() is just returning 1.  Am I doing something wrong, and how can I fix it?
Thank you

Comment: What is the type of `i`?

Comment: `36000` -> `36000.0`.

Comment: If your `i` variable is an integer and less than 36000, then `(i / 36000)` (done in integer arithmetic) will be zero. 1 plus zero is 1, and 1 raised to any power is also 1.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is with the data-type of variable "i"(interest) and maybe you are taking it as an integer. If both numerator and denominator are of integer type then "/" operator does integer division i.e. gives the floor value. So this division results in 0 if (numerator < denominator) and 1+0 = 1.
And eventually, any power to 1 results in 1.

Below are the changes, you can do:

1. Type-cast the variable "i" to float/double
2. Just change 36000 to 36000.0

Comment: I type-casted i and j to double and it works now.  Thank you

Comment: Thanks Balram for this answer please consider this [markdown editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to `format your answer`.